# Cannot run source activate with conda in Fish-shell

Tags: anaconda, fish

I follow [conda_PR_545](https://github.com/conda/conda/pull/545#issuecomment-224833788), [conda issues 4221](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/4221#issuecomment-271343621) and still not working on Ubuntu.

After downloading conda.fish from [here](https://gist.github.com/jiffyclub/9679788), and mv it to anaconda3/bin/.

Add "source /home/phejimlin/anaconda3/bin/conda.fish" at the end of ~/.config/fish/config.fish.

```
conda activate spark_env
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/phejimlin/anaconda3/bin/conda", line 6, in 
sys.exit(conda.cli.main())
File "/home/phejimlin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 161, in main
raise CommandNotFoundError(argv1, message)
TypeError: init() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

or

```
activate spark_env
Error: activate must be sourced. Run 'source activate envname'
instead of 'activate envname'.
```

Do I miss something?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

*As of fish 2.6.0 conda 4.3.27: the following steps may change as [issue is addressed](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/2611)*

## update config

Take note of your `conda`'s location

```
conda info --root
/Users/mstreeter/anaconda    # this is my <PATH_TO_ROOT>
```

Add line to `~/.config/fish/config.fish`

```
 source <PATH_TO_ROOT>/etc/fish/conf.d/conda.fish
```

## update convention

Typically you'd run the following from `bash`

```
source activate <environment>
source deactivate <environment>
```

Now you must run the following from `fish`

```
conda activate <environment>
conda deactivate <environment>
```

## issues

*so after doing this I'm not able to set `fish` as my default shell and have it still work properly with `conda`. Currently, I must first enter my default shell, and enter `fish` and the shell works as expected.  I'll update this after I find out how to get it working completely without the need to explicitly choose `fish` each time I log into my terminal*

Comment: i just tried this and have no problem with having fish as my default shell. after creating a new shell session, my default conda env is correctly activated and shown.

Comment: This works for me but not fully: after I activate a conda env it still points to my system python instead of the conda env's python. Any ideas how to address this?

Comment: update: answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55526314/conda-not-working-correctly-with-fish-shell

Comment: Perfect! Updating the config is all that is needed.

Answer (score 33):

If you follow https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/2611, the steps are (from start):

```
[root@6903a8d80f9b ~]# fish
root@6903a8d80f9b ~# echo $FISH_VERSION 
2.4.0
root@6903a8d80f9b ~# bash Miniconda2-4.3.11-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p /conda
root@6903a8d80f9b ~# source /conda/etc/fish/conf.d/conda.fish
root@6903a8d80f9b ~# conda activate root
root@6903a8d80f9b ~# conda create -yn fishtest                              (root) 
Fetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: 
Package plan for installation in environment /conda/envs/fishtest:

#
# To activate this environment, use:
# > source activate fishtest
#
# To deactivate this environment, use:
# > source deactivate fishtest
#

root@6903a8d80f9b ~# conda activate fishtest                                (root) 
root@6903a8d80f9b ~#                                                    (fishtest) 
root@6903a8d80f9b ~# conda deactivate fishtest                          (fishtest)
```

Comment: WOW! So magic, it's working!
I just add "source (conda info --root)/etc/fish/conf.d/conda.fish" to my config.fish and it's working!

Thank you,  I almost spent all day on this environment setting.

Comment: my answer is basically your answer Nehal, it seemed as if the details were buried in your answer though, so I wrote what I did at my level

Comment: the only question i have, is, why are you working as root. ;)

Comment: For SO answers, I just spawn a new container and I am usually root in them :)

Answer (score 11):

Adding conda's bin directory to PATH isn't recommended as of conda 4.4.0
https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#440-2017-12-20

All you need to do is adding
`source <path-to-anaconda>/etc/fish/conf.d/conda.fish`
to config.fish.

Comment: Since Conda v4.6.0, you should just be able to run `conda init` and it will adjust `config.fish` for you.