# conda not working correctly with fish shell

Tags: python, shell, anaconda, conda, fish

When using conda environments inside the fish shell on macOS, `python` still points to system python (`/usr/local/bin/python`) instead of pointing to the version of python installed by the conda environment (`<PATH TO MINICONDA>/envs/<ENV NAME>/bin/python`). Everything else (e.g. `ipython`, `jupyter`) points to the correct path, just `python` isn't behaving as expected. How do I fix this?

Details:

Performed the following steps in the following order on macOS Mojave 10.14.3:

- Installed miniconda (a while back) via the bash install script
- Installed fish using homebrew
- Updated `config.fish` as per: [Cannot run source activate with conda in Fish-shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42871313/cannot-run-source-activate-with-conda-in-fish-shell/46866470#46866470)

At this point I can activate and deactivate conda environments successfully inside fish, but as noted at the top of this question `python` doesn't point to where it should. Everything else (e.g. `ipython`) works correctly.

`conf info` returns (same inside bash and fish):

```
     active environment : base
    active env location : /Users/salamon/dev/miniconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /Users/salamon/.condarc
 populated config files : 
          conda version : 4.6.11
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.7.1.final.0
       base environment : /Users/salamon/dev/miniconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /Users/salamon/dev/miniconda3/pkgs
                          /Users/salamon/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /Users/salamon/dev/miniconda3/envs
                          /Users/salamon/.conda/envs
               platform : osx-64
             user-agent : conda/4.6.11 requests/2.21.0 CPython/3.7.1 Darwin/18.2.0 OSX/10.14.3
                UID:GID : 501:20
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

Calling `which python` in bash:

```
/Users/salamon/dev/miniconda3/bin/python
```

And in fish:

```
/usr/local/bin/python
```

Any help would be most appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Even when activated? That's strange. Is the system Python somehow still higher precedence in the `$PATH` after you activate?  Could you add `conda info` to your question?

Comment: Yes, even when activated, but only in fish. In bash when activated it points to the correct miniconda install. Added `conda info` and the output of `which python` in bash and fish. Note the output of `conda info` is identical in bash and fish. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> python doesn't point to where it should

Quite simply, that means that there is a path component that includes a python before the one you want. In this case /usr/local/bin is before /envs//bin/ in $PATH (if it's in there at all).

See `command -sa python`, which should print *all* pythons it can, and adjust your $PATH accordingly, possibly by putting the one you want into $fish_user_paths, which is prepended to $PATH.

Comment: This works! To be specific, making sure `/Users/salamon/dev/miniconda3/bin` is first in `$PATH` results in conda correctly pointing to the loaded environment's python for each environment. Thanks!