# Snakemake change conda activation command to 'conda activate'

Tags: bash, conda, snakemake, fish

I want to use snakemake with fish shell and conda environments in my managed environment (basically I have no root rights and the default shell cannot be changed).

I set up fish as the 'default' shell using this hack inside the `.bashrc`:

```sh
if [ "$REALBASH" != "1" ]; then
  case "$-" in
  *i*)
    export SHELL=/usr/bin/fish
    tty > /dev/null && echo "Your ~/.bashrc is switching interactive SHELL to $SHELL"
    [ -x $SHELL ] && exec $SHELL "$@"
    echo "Apparently $SHELL is not available here. Continuing with bash."
    export SHELL=/bin/bash
  ;;
  esac
fi
```

There is also a command `realbash` that sets the environment variable `REALBASH=1` to bypass this hack.

I managed to get conda to work with fish using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42871313/cannot-run-source-activate-with-conda-in-fish-shell), but it has the disadvantage that within fish the command to activate conda environments is different from bash. In bash, the command is `source activate ...` and in fish it is `conda activate ...`.

Activating environments works both from bash using `source activate ...` and from fish using `conda activate ...`.

When I now execute snakemake from fish, I get the following error:

```
Activating conda environment ...
source: Error encountered while sourcing file “activate”:
source: No such file or directory
```

If I execute snakemake from bash, the same error occurs.

If I execute snakemake from bash via `snakemake --overwrite-shellcmd realbash`, I get the same error and end up in the bash shell that was opened by snakemake. Only after typing exit, snakemake completes (but unsuccessfully, of course).
If I execute snakemake from fish via `snakemake --overwrite-shellcmd realbash`, the same behaviour occurs.

I am confused by the behaviour of `--overwrite-shellcmd`, is there a way to make this work with my hack?
Otherwise, can I configure snakemake to call `conda activate` instead of `source activate`?
Or is there any other solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this was a bug in an older version of `snakemake`. The effects described in the question were produced with `snakemake 4.3.1`.

Running `snakemake` from within a `conda` environment where `snakemake 5.17.0` is installed works perfectly fine with the setup as described in the question. No `--overwrite-shellcmd` or other changes are required.